docker build /lib/modules/6.2.0-25-generic/build/scripts
I tried to install a package inside a docker container but ran into this error. I have tried to cpy kernal file into this directory but still have the same problem. Does anyone know how to solve this? Thank you.

Docker is not a full virtualization system.  It does not ship a kernel for any container.  It utilizes the host system for the kernel base.  You cannot build kernel packages or kernel modules in Docker, you have to build/compile them on the host system.  Even then, that does not mean Docker has access to the kernel module.

Is there a way to expose the container to the kernel module?

no.  not without compiling the module into your host system, and even then it's probably restricted.  It  sounds like what you need is a VM not a container.  That way the VM can run a separate kernel from Host system
